# Remove default pi flexform fields from plugin configuration - typo3

Tags: typo3, flux, extbase

I created a typo3 extension.I have a flex form for configuring my pluggin.The form contains some default typo3 configuration like pluggin mode,storage folder and recursive.I want to hide these fields.How can it is possible?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following in your ext_tables.php file

```
$TCA['tt_content']['types']['list']['subtypes_excludelist'][$pluginSignature] = 'recursive,select_key,pages';
```

Comment: vrithiketta poraattu naadakam ;)